# Python 3.7 Django 2 Request POST

Tags: python-3.x, post, request, django-2.0

I'm trying to send a POST request to a Django server. I want to use the data of my dict in Django.

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django 2.0.7

Client code:

```
var array = {
    products: [{
        id: "B10", 
        amount: "2"}], 
    payment: {
        type: "payment-slip", 
        data: {
            name: "DEFECTO", 
            dni: "99999999"}}, 
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

$.post("{% url 'erp:seller.sell' %}", array, function (data) {
    ...
});
```

Server Code:

```
@login_required
def sell(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        [...]
```

I have tried to read the data:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

but I got this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```